# Prove that tree has independent set

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every tree with $n$ vertices has an independent set with the size of $\lceil \frac{n}  {2} \rceil$.

Okay, I think I understand the concept of this whole thing. I understand, that we are searching for a proof, which proves that the number of vertices colored by the same color in a tree is max $\frac{n}{2}$. I can imagine e.g. a tree with every vertices having degree 1.

I just have a problem formally proving it. I can't prove it neither with contradiction nor with induction.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T$ be a tree with $n$ vertices. Pick any vertex $v$ to be the root. If $u$ is any vertex of $T$, there is a unique shortest path from $v$ to $u$; color $u$ red if the length of this path is even and blue if it is odd. Show that the set of red vertices is independent, as is the set of blue vertices. Say there are $r$ red and $b$ blue vertices; then $r+b=n$, so what can you say about $\max\{r,b\}$?

Comment: great minds think alike.

Comment: @Omnitic: Even the same colors, though we did switch them!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Any tree can be colored in just two colors.

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary point on the vertex, color it blue. and colour vertices at an even distance with red, and vertices with an odd distance with blue. if a blue and blue vertex are adjacent then that is a contradiction. analogously for the red ones.

exactly one of those is at least $\lceil \frac{n}  {2} \rceil$.