# Proving that a tree of n vertices has an independent set of the size $\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I will probably try to prove this through induction, by coloring a graph into 2 colors, but I was told, that I need to somehow resolve the issue of new vertices possibly being adjacent.

I tried looking into a similar problem like this one [Prove that tree has independent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/593085), yet I don't quite understand the answers.  know

Another option that I have heard of is saying that a tree is a bipartite graph and basically that's like half the proof.

So the reason I am posting this question is that I would like to how can I prove the property from the question by induction or by stating that a tree is a bipartite graph.

Answer (score 1):

The coloring idea works just fine. Once you properly color the tree with two colors, one sees that each color class is an indepenedent set. Since there are two color classes and $n$ vertices, there must be a color class with at least $\lceil n/2\rceil$ vertices.

EDIT: So I guess your main concern is why a tree is bipartite (2-colorable). One can use Konig's theorem which says that a graphs is bipartite if and only if there is no odd cycle in it. Since a tree has no cycle it is bipartite. But, of course, one can give a direct argument.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to show that any tree with size $n$ has an independent set of size at least $\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$. Someone has suggested you attempt an inductive argument on the number of vertices, but to be careful with the colouring of newly added vertices in the inductive step. However, if you colour the graph in the way indicated by the answer you linked, then there is no such problem; for any node in a tree always has only one incident edge (from its father node), which will inevitably be of a different colour from any of its sons, can you see why?